# Install Xamarin - VS Installer "Available" tab with not items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Hi I'm willing to install Xamarin as per MS youtube video, 
I launched VS Installer but found nothing in "Available" tab.

I just updated Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, 3 minutes ago and restarted it.

So I'm now stuck, can't install Xamarin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issued fixed following the below links.

I just needed to click "Modify" in VS Installer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019